# List append in a "for" loop

Tags: python, list, loops, append, iteration

I am trying to get a list of elements using a `for` loop to index my previous list. Here's the code:

```
for index in range(1,810):
    list.extend(t[index])
    list.extend(t[index+1])
    list.extend(t[index])
```

I already have a `list` named "list" and `t` is an other `list`.
To be more specific I want to make my list like this.

```
t1,t2,t1,t2,t3,t2,t3,t4 etc.
```

I get this error `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`.

Comment: A word of caution: don't shadow built-in names like `list`.

Comment: `extend` ≠ `append`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `list.append` since `list.extend` works on iterables; i.e. you can do stuff like `lst=[1,2,3];lst.extend([4,5])` which would give you `[1,2,3,4,5]`

see [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) if you want to read more

Comment: Well at first i have just list[0] = t0. Your ideas dont work

Answer (score 0):

The other answers suggesting you use append fix your issue, but appending is very inefficient. You should use a list comprehension. Also, "list" is a keyword, so you should use another name.

```
 my_list = [item for index in range(1,810) for item in [t[index],t[index+1],t[index]] ]
```

Comment: list[0]=t[0]
list = [item for index in range(1,810) for item in [t[index],t[index+1],t[index]] ]
i used this and i want list to have t0,t1,t2,t1,t2,t3 etc. But i get this error 'type' object does not support item assignment

Comment: @r4diohead Did you write your comment before seeing my edit? "list" is a keyword, so you need another name.